# how to backup a 20TB database in a network?

Tags: postgresql

i have a postgres database the size is 20TB i need a custom format of pg_dump. I try via network backup but it always ending disconnected. Is there a way i can backup this data where it will be every 1TB it will create a dump file.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

Back up only portions of your database such as schema or table

Use compressed dumps

```
pg_dump dbname | gzip > filename.gz
```

Use split. The split command allows you to split the output into smaller files that are acceptable in size to the underlying file system. For example, to make chunks of 1 megabyte

```
pg_dump dbname | split -b 1m - filename
```

Backup: database in compressed splited files of 1TB size.

```
 pg_dump -d dbname | gzip | split -b 1000000m – filename
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/backup-dump.html

Comment: is there an option for if it loose connection I can re run the command and start where it stops?